# SonarQube JIRA integration - incorrect link generated in JIRA description field

Tags: sonarqube, jira, sonarqube5.2

When raising tickets from SonarQube 5.2 using JIRA plugin v1.2, the text within the issue description contains the following markup:

```
Issue detail:

{quote}
[Description of issue]
{quote}

Check it on Sonar: [value set in sonar.core.serverBaseURL]/issue/show/[issue ID]
```

The URL that is generated results in an error page (The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.)

However when altering the URL to the below (note the additional 's' to pluralise issue > issues)

[value set in sonar.core.serverBaseURL]/**issues**/show/[issue ID]

the request is properly redirected to

[value set in sonar.core.serverBaseURL]/issues/search#issues=[issue ID]

Is there a way to alter the URL that is sent to JIRA's description field via configuration, or is there an update to the plugin which addresses this?

Comment: I am having the same issue with SonarQube 5.3 and JIRA 1.2. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @JirongHu not yet, I have instructed our team to use the link ticket issue and manually correct the hyperlink for now. Disappointing, as everything else about the product is excellent..